# Capable DateTime Picker (Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I tried several Bootstrap-friendly Date/Time Picker components allowing for manual input as well as a picker (I need both). I had a look at, for instance, components by eonasdan, uxsolutions and others.

While they all look neat, they fail to do reasonable error checking of the manual entry field, and as far as I experienced they fail to return the date in UTC. I need a component which takes a default in UTC, displays it as local date/time using the device's language/regional settings, validates the input, and returns UTC again.

If the user input verification fails, the input field should be highlighted, probably an error indication displayed somewhere. It is inacceptable that the component tries to "guess" from a faulty input, like some controls letting me enter February 31th, and silently changing that to March 3rd.

Furthermore I need a solution working with the majority of browsers still in use, including Internet Explorer 8.

Can anyone suggest a component I can try?

Comment: as far as normalizing dates and UTC parsing/formatting, I use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard finding a library taking care of all those things, at least i havent come across any such.  But you can take any one of these and tweak it to your needs.

https://libraries.io/search?keywords=datetime&languages=JavaScript

For example take this fiddle, it fixed the timezone issue with bootstrap datetimepicker to fit his needs, you can do something similar :